# Difference between CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED and STATE_CHANGED

Tags: android, bluetooth

What's the difference between Action CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED and STATE_CHANGED in Android Bluetooth Receiver ?

```
            else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED .equals(action)) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_CONNECTION_STATE,
                    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTED);
                if (state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    //nothing
                } else {

                }
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
            if (state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF) {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html) the difference is the following:

```
ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
```

Intent used to broadcast the change in connection state of the local Bluetooth adapter to a profile of the remote device.

```
ACTION_STATE_CHANGED
```

The state of the local Bluetooth adapter has been changed. For example, Bluetooth has been turned on or off.

In other words one `Intent` is for changes in the connection state and the other one for state changes of the Bluetooth adapter itself.

**EDIT:**

To detect if a device moves in and out of range you need to use the following intents:

- `ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED`: [link to documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED)
- `ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED`: [link to documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED)

For both of those you need the normal `BLUETOOTH` permission and the `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

The intent filter for your `BroadcastReceiver` would look something like this:

```
<intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
    <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
</intent-filter>
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html) is the general documentation about `BluetoothDevice`.

Comment: which of them is called when for example the device goes out of range ?

Comment: I'm not sure either one of them is called in this case. You should really just look into the docs yourself because I'm basically just copying and pasting from there. `ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED` is only send when the first device connects or the last one disconnects. This intent is all about the general connection state of the adapter itself and not devices that are connected to it. `ACTION_STATE_CHANGED` again has nothing to do with devices but deals with the state of the adapter for example if bluetooth is turned on or off.

Comment: But I think I already know what you are looking for. Give me a few minutes and I will edit a solution into my answer.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Shouldn't the second permission required for observing ACL_CONNECTED/ACL_DISCONNECTED be BLUETOOTH_CONNECT (not BLUETOOTH_ADMIN)?